# JQuery Slide down/up - Display only one div from the same class name

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created UL list, each LI has two DIVs - one visible question tab and one hidden answer tab. There is a button on the right side of the tabs (Question tab has SlideDown button, answer tab has SlideUp button). But once I click on these buttons, it shows all DIVs in the entire UL list. How can I display only the clicked content and let the remaining DIVs be hidden?

HTML looks as following:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="questionTab" id="firstTab">What is the natural color for Dory?
        <span class="slideDownButton" style="background-color: red">SLIDEDOWN</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answerTab">Answer: It's blue. 
        <span class="slideUpButton" style="background-color: red">SLIDEUP</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For this post, I excluded general layout such as paddings, margins, colors etc.

```
.answerTab {
    display: none;
    }
```

And JQuery script looks like following which will currently open all tabs in UL:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slideDownButton").click(function(){
            $(".answerTab").slideDown("slow");
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slideUpButton").click(function(){
            $(".answerTab").slideUp("slow");
        });
    });
```

However, based on some research some people had similar issue as me and I tried to make following adjustments to display only the clicked DIV, so it eventually looks like this, but it's not working.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slideDownButton").click(function(){
            $(this).parent("li").find(".answerTab").slideDown("slow");
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slideUpButton").click(function(){
            $(this).parent("li").find(".answerTab").slideUp("slow");
        });
    });
```

So I ask your help and advice. How can I improve the following code and what am I doing wrong? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first JQuery code works, except there are two errors.

1. You only should call `$(document).ready` once at the beginning of the script. You should wrap your JQuery code with the `$(document).ready` function.
2. You wrote: `$(",answerTab").slideUp("slow");` - the class name `answerTab` should have a period, not a comma. So it should be written like so: `$(".answerTab").slideUp("slow");`

Below is a working version of your code. You can also check out this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/oeVzXj)**. I hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slideDownButton").click(function() {
    $(".answerTab").slideDown("slow");
  });
  $(".slideUpButton").click(function() {
    $(".answerTab").slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.answerTab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="questionTab" id="firstTab">What is the natural color for Dory?
      <span class="slideDownButton" style="background-color: red">SLIDEDOWN</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answerTab">Answer: It's blue.
      <span class="slideUpButton" style="background-color: red">SLIDEUP</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

For multiple list items with questions and answers, you can traverse the DOM with the JQuery methods `parent` and `next` like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slideDownButton").click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".questionTab").next(".answerTab").slideDown("slow");
  });
  $(".slideUpButton").click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".answerTab").slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.answerTab {
  display: none;
}

li {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
}

span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #E00;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="questionTab">What is the natural color for Dory?
      <span class="slideDownButton">SLIDEDOWN</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answerTab">Answer: It's blue.
      <span class="slideUpButton">SLIDEUP</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="questionTab">What is the natural color for Woof?
      <span class="slideDownButton">SLIDEDOWN</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answerTab">Answer: It's brown.
      <span class="slideUpButton">SLIDEUP</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="questionTab">What is the natural color for Wolf?
      <span class="slideDownButton">SLIDEDOWN</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answerTab">Answer: It's grey.
      <span class="slideUpButton">SLIDEUP</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My God, I made a mistake when I tried to show the first code which worked but made a mistake. There was indeed supposed to be a dot. Thank you for pointing it out. But how can I show only one DIV and let the remaining ones be hidden?

Comment: This actually shows only one `div` at a time by showing and hiding the `div` class name `answerTab` i.e. there are 2 `div`s (`questionTab` and `answerTab`) - this code shows and hides the `answerTab` `div`. Do you want to show and hide the list items? This is also possible.

Comment: Yes, originally UL contains around 6-8 list items. I just copied only one in here. The first JQuery script works fine if there is only one list item in UL. But if there are two or more LIs in UL, then it shows answerTab divs for all of them upon clicking it. Each questionTab would have a different question, same goes for answerTabs. But you only display one answerTab at a time - specifically the one that you click on. My question is how can I show toggle only the clicked one and keep the remaining ones as they are.

Comment: I see - I updated the **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/ayMmxm)** - I'll also add the code above for clarity.

Comment: Thank you so much! Updated code in the Codepen Demo was the answer I was looking for. :)

Comment: Great :) I'm glad it helped.